# What is the difference between these two delegate statements?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm looking at delegates for the first time and wondered what the differnce is between these two styles.

```
OfferList.NextPage += delegate(int page)
{
    OnNextPage(page);
};


void OnNextPage(int page)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
Toolbar.OfferBookmarkRemoved += new OfferBookmarkRemoved(OnOfferBookmarkRemoved);

void OnOfferBookmarkRemoved(int offerId)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A third option is `Toolbar.OfferBookmarkRemoved += OnOfferBookmarkRemoved;`

Comment: Or `Offer_List1.NextPage += (page) => OnNextPage(page);`

Comment: or `Toolbar.OfferBookmarkRemoved += page=>{.....};`

Comment: Lol, sorry I asked - is there any benefit that one offers over the others or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: @user1437135 don't be sorry, it's a good question. And all of the suggestions boils down to the same thing - when the event `NextPage` or `OfferBookmarkRemoved` happens, call the method after the `+=`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is an [Anonymous Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and the second is a Name Method.

See also [Delegates with Named vs. Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98dc08ac%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)